# Receiving "." in iPhone push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

We have an already published app in iOS, for some iPhone users they're receiving notification as a dot. While for ipad users we're receiving it with the correct data. 
We're almost certain that this is a device issue but how can it be fixed and could it be something else? 
Need help on how to troubleshoot/fix this problem.

Comment: what is the payload Json?

Comment: This question does not have enough detail to be able to even attempt giving a useful answer.  Did you set a breakpoint in your ["`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: `"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) method?  If so, look at the `userInfo` dictionary and see if the dot appears there, or if it is appearing somewhere along the way to your push notification handling code.